# Pythonic way to check which variable equals zero?

Tags: python

What would be the best way to find which of your given variables equals zero? I can do this, but this won't tell me which of the variables equals zero.

```
if 0 in (a, b, c, d, e):
    do something
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the desired output or action, currently 'do something' doesn't care what variable triggered it? In what way do you need to know which variable is zero: a print statement? its string name? or what? If you have 5 variables, you could use 5 if-statements.

Comment: What kind of output do you expect to know which variable is zero? Please remember that objects don't know the names of references pointing to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're in this situation at all, it's a sign you probably should have used a list or some other data structure instead of 5 variables.

How would you even express the information "variable `c` was the one" in a way your program could use? `which_one_was_it = c`? That would just set `which_one_was_it` to 0 (or technically maybe 0.0 or something). `which_one_was_it = 'c'`? What are you going to do with the letter `'c'`? Even if you abuse `eval` or `locals`, all you can do is retrieve the value again. `eval`, `exec`, and `locals` cannot be used to reassign local variables.

In contrast, if you had a 5-element list, `index = l.index(0)` would tell you the first index with a value equal to 0, and `l[index] = 5` could be used to set the value at that index.

Comment: Good nice one, use `globals` outside function

Comment: One possible justification: you are counting the number of variables which failed a check against 0, and you're firing an event for each one, or using this count for something.

Answer (score 1):

Or list comprehension:

```
print([do something for i in (a,b,c,d,e) if i == 0])
```

Or:

```
print([do something for i in (a,b,c,d,e) if not i])
```

Or a generator (do list(..) to convert to list):

```
print((do something for i in (a,b,c,d,e) if not i))
```

to get which one:

```
>>> a=0
>>> b=1
>>> c=0
>>> d=1
>>> e=0
>>> [k for k,v in globals().items() if not v]
['__doc__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__annotations__', 'a', 'c', 'e']
>>> [k for k,v in globals().items() if v==0]
['a', 'c', 'e']
>>>
```